# Uploading multiple files per field and storing in a db with codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form which uploads multiple file fields into a db using codeigniter.

I need to be able to upload multiple files for each field. I understand that this could be achieved using some jquery magic, however, my problem is how do I intercept the multiple files and what is the best way to store them in my database?

At the minute I just have one field which stores the file location/name, would I need to insert all the files as one long comma seperated string? If so, how do I then make use of that string for my view functions to show each file?

Sorry if the above doesn't make sense, I can explain in more detail or post my code if required.

Thanks for any help in advance

Dan

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what it is you're asking? You have already said you're uploading multiple files into a database, so are what is it you're wanting to know other than storing the files? RE storing the files, I think keeping them in a directory and referencing the path is good practice. Of course they could be stored as binary in the database, but that could really bloat your database if the files get large.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I mean selecting and uploading multiple files per field!  At the minute I have 4 fields which each upload 1 file at a time, but at least two of the fields may need to upload 3 files at a time.

Hope this is clearer?

Comment: Ok I think I understand what you are saying. You could separate the values with a comma, pipe, or any separator you wish into one field, or you could have each one stored in it's own row. Is there any reason you want to store them all in one row? If you insist on storing them in one row, I'd use a pipe symbol (|) or other uncommon character that you wont find in a file name.

Comment: There is no reason for them being in one row, but wouldn't that mean a database field would have to be created on the fly if multiple files were uploaded?

Comment: AAAAH I see, you will no doubt need to make use of jQuery or any other JS to achieve this. The standard HTML file browser only allows you to select one file.

Comment: RE database rows being made on the fly, no it would not mean that rows would be populated for each upload on the fly, ultimately the data is sent as an array in the end, so you end up being able to process all your data with one script / page / however you wish to process it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pains me to say this, but the best method of uploading multiple files at once is to use a plugin like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

With regard to how you'd like to store it in the database...If you're allowing a single user to upload multiple files, I'd recommend having three tables:

1. Users (user_id, username, email, etc.)
2. Files (file_id, filepath, time_uploaded, etc.)
3. Users_files (user_id, file_id)

Then when you store the files on your server, you can insert a new row into your "files" table. Then when you delete files, be sure to remove the row in the files table and the association in the users_files table.